# Чтение статических переменных из разных потоков потокобезопасно?

Tags: c#, .net

Потокобезопасно ли чтение статических переменных из разных потоков? Переменные как ссылочного типа, так и типа значения. Переменные инициализируются только один раз в статическом конструкторе, и нигде далее в коде их значения не меняются.

Comment: Если они никогда не меняются, то в чем опасность-то?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, начитался EN SO, решил уточнить. =)

Comment: @АндрейNOP так мож ответом?

Comment: @tym32167, да я как-то хз что там написать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ответьте, подобного вопроса вроде еще небыло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потокобезопасность подразумевает, что данные, записанные одним потоком, будут правильно считаны другим. Ну допустим, у вас потоки создают экземпляры некого класса и в нем есть статическая переменная – счетчик созданных экземпляров, которая инкрементируется в конструкторе. В этом случае может произойти такая ситуация, что один из потоков прочитал переменную и до того как записал увеличенное на 1 значение обратно, это сделал другой поток, а затем первый поток перезапишет это значение на *теперь уже* неверное.

Если же переменные неизменяемые, как у вас, то и опасности никакой нет.