# Task.Run(): работа с разделяемыми ресурсами

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, task, распараллеливание

Есть код

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"c:\test\test.txt";
        string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
        Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
                 .Select(i => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var destFilePath = Path.Combine(tempPath, $"{i.ToString()}.txt");
                File.Copy(filePath, destFilePath);

                //... process destFile

            })).ToArray());
        Debug.WriteLine(tempPath);
    }
}
```

где просиходит создание копий файла `test.txt` и их обработка в многопоточном режиме. Здесь сразу хочется отметить свое понимание разницы между многопоточно и паралельно: если при создании очередно потока, окажеться свободным одно из ядер процесса, то обработка очередной копии файла и во все будет запущенна параллельно.

---

### Вопрос

Сейчас ведь в различных потоках идет доступ к разделяемому ресурсу `test.txt` и никакой синхронизации потоков я не делаю как видите и почему тогда все проходит гладко и никаких exception нет? Или `Task.WaitAll()` сам делает синхронизацию?

Comment: Вы же только читаете, какие могут быть проблемы? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816356/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP, имелось ввиду: что происходит когда один поток начал чтение файла и второй, который оказался запущенным параллельно тоже пытается осуществить чтение того же файла? Разве не должно выскакивать что-то типа: FileDoNotAccessException?

Comment: Ну там наверное нет блокировки при чтении, зачем она?

Comment: Не нужно копировать файл несколько раз! Это очень медленная операция. Считайте содержимое файла в память и обрабатывайте параллельно (конечно, если всё влезает в память). Читать данные можно спокойно из нескольких потоков, без какой-либо конкуренкции.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если файл не велик.