# Является ли потокобезопасным атомарный инкремент переменной-счетчика?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Дана переменная-счетчик типа `int`, в нескольких потоках и\или асинхронных задачах в нее пишется (атомарный инкремент) и еще несколько потоков читают ее значение.

Во всех ли случаях атомарность даст гарантию [потокобезопасности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816356)?

Comment: тут вполне может быть read-write race condition, почему вы считаете, что такая вещь как атомарность операции поможет от этого избавиться?

Comment: Interlocked.Increment/Decrement в этом случае должен вам помочь.